# datadog.apiKey was 'null' but it is required

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, micrometer

I am currently using spring boot `2.7.0-M1` and following is my dependencies in `build.gradle`:

```
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-datadog:latest.release'
    datadogagent("com.datadoghq:dd-java-agent:$datadoghq_dd_version")
    implementation("com.datadoghq:dd-trace-api:${datadoghq_dd_version}")
```

However, when i try to set micrometer bean:

```
@Configuration
public class MeterRegistryConfig {
  @Bean
  MeterRegistry meterRegistry(ApplicationContext context) {
    DatadogConfig config = new DatadogConfig() {
      @Override
      public Duration step() {
        return Duration.ofSeconds(10);
      }

      @Override
      public String get(String k) {
        return null; // accept the rest of the defaults
      }
    };

    return new DatadogMeterRegistry(config, Clock.SYSTEM);
  }
}
```

I am getting a startup error:

```
2022-02-05 05:07:56.457 ERROR 7897 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'webMvcMetricsFilter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/web/servlet/WebMvcMetricsAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'webMvcMetricsFilter' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'compositeMeterRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/CompositeMeterRegistryConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'compositeMeterRegistry' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'meterRegistry' defined in class path resource [com/hbomax/ml/mlsvc/config/MeterRegistryConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry]: Factory method 'meterRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is io.micrometer.core.instrument.config.validate.ValidationException: datadog.apiKey was 'null' but it is required
2022-02-05 05:07:56.504  INFO 7897 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-02-05 05:07:56.520  WARN 7897 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2022-02-05 05:07:56.541  INFO 7897 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
```

Here's my `application.yaml`:

```
management:
  info:
    git:
      mode: full
  metrics:
    distribution:
      percentiles:
        http:
          server:
            requests: 0.5, 0.95, 0.99
      percentiles-histogram:
        http:
          server:
            requests: true
      sla:
        http:
          server:
            requests: 200ms, 400ms, 600ms
    export:
      datadog:
        step: 30s
        enabled: true
        api-key: xxxxxxx
    tags:
      application: ${spring.application.name}
      env: ${spring.profiles}
```

Can someone help me understand what is the issue? I tried searching around but din't get any solution. I tried replacing `api-key` with `apiKey`(I know it's silly) but no success.

Any help folks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Spring Boot's configuration properties in `application.yml` but you are also making your own `DatadogMeterRegistry` that doesn't use those configuration properties, and therefore it will not have the required API key configuration.

You can delete the `MeterRegistryConfig` class entirely and instead use the `DatadogMeterRegistry` that Spring Boot will auto-configure from configuration properties because you have the `micrometer-registry-datadog` dependency on your classpath. See [this section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator.metrics.getting-started) of the Spring Boot documentation.

Comment: Let me test and get back to you on this. Thanks for the quick clarification! New to instrumentation :)

Comment: You were correct. Thanks for pointing this out. Apologies for late comment.

Answer (score 3):

For me, it was just the hierarchy is changed when updated from Spring boot 2 -> 3.

**Update the below:**

```
management:
  .....
  metrics: // Changed to datadog
    .....
    export: // Changed to metrics
      datadog: // Changed to export
        step: 30s
        enabled: true
        api-key: xxxxxxx
    .....
```

**To :**

```
management:
  .....
  datadog:
    .....
    metrics:
      export:
        step: 30s
        enabled: true
        api-key: xxxxxxx
    .....
```