# io.micrometer.core.instrument.config.validate.ValidationException: datadog.apiKey was 'null' but it is required

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, datadog, micrometer

I am using spring boot 2.7.7 and below are my maven dependencies:
[image: Dependencies]

Here, is how I set the DatadogConfig in my controller:

```
DatadogConfig config = new DatadogConfig() {
            @Override
            public Duration step() {
                return Duration.ofSeconds(10);
            }

            @Override
            public String get(String k) {
                return null; // accept the rest of the defaults
            }
        };
        logger.info(appConfig.getApiKey());
        MeterRegistry registry = new DatadogMeterRegistry(config, Clock.SYSTEM);
```

My application.yml is set as below:

```
management.metrics.export.datadog:
  apiKey: "******"

  # You will probably want disable Datadog publishing in a local development profile.
  enabled: true

  # The interval at which metrics are sent to Datadog. The default is 1 minute.
  step: "1m"
server:
  port: 8081
```

After running the application, I do see that the Meter registry is trying to push metrics, however after sending a request to controller, I get the exception as shown below:

```
i.m.c.instrument.push.PushMeterRegistry  : publishing metrics for DatadogMeterRegistry every 1m
i.m.datadog.DatadogMeterRegistry         : An application key must be configured in order for unit information to be sent to Datadog.
........
io.micrometer.core.instrument.config.validate.ValidationException: datadog.apiKey was 'null' but it is required
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.config.validate.Validated$Either.orThrow(Validated.java:375) ~[micrometer-core-1.9.6.jar:1.9.6]
```

I did follow these posts, but still getting the error
[Micrometer](https://micrometer.io/docs/registry/datadog)

[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70997020/datadog-apikey-was-null-but-it-is-required)

What config am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have two `DatadogMeterRegistry` instances. Spring Boot creates one for you  and you set its config values in your property file. You also create an instance manually (I have no idea why) that you only set the step (btw the two steps you set are different).

Solution: delete the code you wrote and do not create the registry manually. If you must create a registry for some reason, you need to create it as a `@Bean`.